# New to Pytest, and having a hard time figuring out how fixtures should be used correctly

Tags: python, pytest

Trying to refactor some old terrible test code and doing so with Pytest. The tests look something like this:

```
Test/
    Tests_a/
        test_a_foo.py
        test_a_bar.py
        test_a_baz.py
   Tests_b/
       test_b_1.py
       test_b_2.py
       test_b_3.py
```

We want to run Tests_a and Tests_b separately, so I can just call pytest Tests_a, and pytest Tests_b.

There are some value that we need to generate once and have used in most tests.

`common_value1 = "something" + random()
 common_value2 = "something2" + random()
 ...`

Right now i'm doing it by making each of these variables their own fixture in conftest.py. So I have

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def common_value1():
    return "something" + random()
```

So far this seems to work, but i'm wondering if there's a better way? We have a lot of these common values, so it's annoying to fill up conftest with these variables.

`

`

The other issue is that I have some common utility functions I want to break out at the root level of tests. The problem i'm having is that some of these utilities require those common values. Is it possible for non-test functions to get the fixtures?

So I have `util.py` which has something like:

```
def do_common_thing(passed_in_value):
    print(common_value1 + passed_in_value)
```

What's the correct way to get common_value1? I've tried turning this function into a fixture as well and taking common_value1 as a parameter, but that doesn't seem to be valid. The only way i've gotten it to work is to have the tests themselves get common_value1 and pass it into do_common_thing(), but this is particularly annoying when there are alot of these values.

Comment: passing fixture to another fixture should be perfectly valid, and you can compose them that way, but you need to be sure that this other fixture is "visible" in that particular place - fixtures can be imported, and can be put in a hierarchy of conftest.py files. IIRC one way of looking up visible fixtures would be to pass the request fixture and looking it up with a debugger